# session time out with angularjs and asp. net web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, session-timeout

Im using mvc4 web api project.  i have included angularjs. 
as i have read an articles that session is not supported in we api as it is stateless. 
basically we used to do coding with asp. net session.  which is now not there. (it is there but i havent implemented yet).

if i dont plan to use session,  how should i go ahead?  currently i m storing user name in html local storage but it doesnt seem promising as it resides at client side.
how can i show msg of session time out after 10 mins?

should i go with client side js only?
ot there are some ways??? 
i dont know to handle such situation?

timerjs or something?  what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, storing client session in client side is a bad practice as it can be hack easily which result in a vulnerable website. I recommend to use [OAUTH2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc) if you are developing web api. On the client side, you can use [ng-idle](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle) to show the users if they are idle for a long time and log them out on timeout.

Hope this help